# Returning error message with variables

Tags: solidity, require

Suppose I have `require(..., "error")` but instead, I want the error message to be "error var" where `var` is a variable of type string, or uint.

What should I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [custom errors](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

error Unauthorized();

contract VendingMachine {
    address payable owner = payable(msg.sender);

    function withdraw() public {
        if (msg.sender != owner)
            revert Unauthorized();

        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    // ...
}
```

In fact, I highly recommend you switch to custom errors. They are a godsend for Ethereum development. Compared to revert reason strings, custom errors are easier to work with, more gas efficient, and more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your custom errors quite descriptive with vars

contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

error InvalidNumber(uint32 required, uint32 passed);
    
contract CustomErrors{

    uint32 private constant magicNumber = 42;
        
    function checkMagicNumber(uint32 _number) public pure {
        if (_number != magicNumber)
            revert InvalidNumber({
                required: magicNumber,
                passed: _number
            });

        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

result calling function passing 21

```
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: CustomErrors.(constructor)value: 0 weidata: 0x608...a0033logs: 0hash: 0xf34...6204d
transact to CustomErrors.checkMagicNumber pending ... 
transact to CustomErrors.checkMagicNumber errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Error provided by the contract:
InvalidNumber
Parameters:
{
 "required": {
  "value": "42"
 },
 "passed": {
  "value": "21"
 }
}
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
require(var > 0, string(abi.encodePacked("error ", var);
```

I thought you could use string() to concatenate strings as of 0.8.0 but I tested and it didn't work for me:

```
require(var > 0, string("error ", var);
```

Hope this helps. :)